# Push into the first object inside an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this

```
[ { name: 'name1' },
  { name: 'name2' },
  { name: 'name3' } ]
```

and i want to push another object inside each one of them like this :

```
[ { name: 'name1', item: [{ type: type1 }] },
  { name: 'name2', item: [{ type: type2 }] },
  { name: 'name3', item: [{ type: type3 }] } ]
```

When i try to do `array.push({item: [{}]})`, i get my result like this :

```
[ { name: 'name1' },
  { item: [ {} ] },
  { name: 'name2' },
  { item: [ {} ] },
  { name: 'name3' },
  { item: [ {} ] } ]
```

Comment: You can't use `push` here, the elements in the array already exist, you have to modify them.

Comment: do you have an array of `types` ?

Comment: best way to do this is probably just a basic `.forEach` loop.

Comment: no types are just objects that i retreive as strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr1 = [ 
    { name: 'name1', item: [] },
    { name: 'name2', item: [] },
    { name: 'name3', item: [] } 
];

const objects = [
        { itemId: 1 },
        { itemId: 2 },
        { itemId: 3 }
];

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    const element = arr1[i];
    element.item.push(objects[i]);
}

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You first have to initialise `item` as an array:

```
if (!array[0].item) {
    array[0].item = [];
}
```

Then push:

```
array[0].item.push({ type: type1 });
```

Substitute `[0]` for the index you need. I have no clue what the logic is there for you. Probably `array[i]` in some form of loop.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the array and modify the objects the way you want.

```
myArray.forEach((obj, idx) => {

   //You have each object here
   obj.item = [{ type: 'type' + idx }]
})
```

Also look at Array functions like `find`, `some` and `every`

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over and add key-value pair in JSON object

```
array.forEach((element)=>{
   element[0]['item'] = [{}] // here you can add your key-value pair
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also work in case you need a new array

```js
let ar=[ 
  { name: 'name1' },
  { name: 'name2' },
  { name: 'name3' } ];
  
let modArray = ar.map((x,i)=>{
  return {item:[{ type: 'type' + (i+1) }],...x}
});

console.log(modArray);
```